# How to reverse the scroll direction in Windows8?

Tags: windows-8, scrolling, start-screen, logitech-touchpad

I can do a 2-finger swipe on my trackpad to scroll the tiles left and right in Windows 8 Modern UI, but every time I do it, it scrolls in the opposite direction I'd expect. Is there a way to reverse it?

---

If relevant, I'm using the [Logitech K400r](http://www.logitech.com/en-sg/product/Wireless-touch-keyboard-k400r)

Comment: Maybe someone can help if you care to mention your hardware details, which trackpad software you use etc.

Comment: @Karan: Logitech k400r. I assumed this would be a Windows setting, so i didn't think the hardware was relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change this setting as soon as I started to play with Windows 8.1.

Just follow the directions laid out in this tutorial and you'll be all set.

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/38359-precision-touchpad-scroll-direction-set-windows-8-1-a.html

Comment: Link-only answers are considered low quality answers on this site, because if the link ceases to exist, the answer won't be helpful anymore. Please include all necessary details directly in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @miroxlav, I'm on mobile right now. It will have to do. Instead of critiquing my post, couldn't you just copy and paste the links content instead? Seems a bit more useful to users then your previous remark. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not chasing you, just do it when you return to PC, or even from the mobile. Copy-paste is not needed, I see you can type without problems even from the mobile. So just describe the steps in your own words. (Copy-paste without giving a source can also make copyringht infringement.). I understand you might not have known that link-only answers are not welcome at this site. Now you know, take it as constructive learning of something essential. I'm not against facts contained in your answer, they were very valuable. So just post thorough answers and you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your Logitech device has special software utility called **SetPoint** which allows various adjustments of keyboard and trackpad on your device.

You can download it from [K400r support page](http://support.logitech.com/product/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400r#download).

**Since SetPoint 6.51.8** you can enable "Natural scrolling" which reverses scrolling direction.

Open SetPoint, go to *Scrolling* tab, click on *Scrolling options* and check the first option.