# How to reverse scroll direction in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, scrolling

I tried it like here
https://windowsreport.com/reverse-scroll-direction-windows-10

However, hp folio 13 doesn't have HID key and FlipFlopWheel there. Touchpad key is in ACPI. So I added there in Device Parameters FlipFlopWheel DWORD key, set it to 1 and restarted and to 0 also. No luck with both ways. Is there another way to set this simple option?

Comment: Similar question here....https://superuser.com/questions/547747/how-to-reverse-the-scroll-direction-in-windows8?rq=1  and here....https://superuser.com/questions/948348/how-can-i-invert-touchpad-scroll-direction-on-windows-10?rq=1

Comment: And none of these answers work. I don't have an option in Windows to turn off natural scrolling. Like it says here: `Important: The reverse scrolling option is only available for devices with a precision touchpad. If the option isn't available, you may still be able to change the scrolling behavior using the manufacturer software for the peripheral.` And I tried registry edititng, original HP drivers and software only for Win7 available and also AutoHotKey script which changes sensitivity. This should be simple and obvious, but is not. Bad desing.

Answer (score 5):

Your link has a second and better solution by using
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/),
and it even supplies the script to use:

```
WheelUp::
Send {WheelDown}
Return
WheelDown::
Send {WheelUp}
Return
```

Or with some improvements:

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
#HotkeyInterval 4000
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 300

WheelUp::WheelDown
WheelDown::WheelUp
```

This solution has a much better chance of working than monkeying with
the registry and counting on the driver to take notice.

The link contains very explicit directions on setting this up.
Further information can be found on the AutoHotkey website, with many tutorials.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't see this. However, when I run this script it changes how many lines are scrolled. It messed up sensitivity.

Comment: I added a second formulation with might work better. How exactly are you scrolling? (regarding hardware use, touchpad or what)

Comment: Yes, touchpad with two fingers. I would like that page goes down when moving fingers down.

Comment: What is your computer and touchpad?

Comment: 4 years later... thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. It's never too late!